# Calling a method in the parent component from a child component using blazor server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server for my development and have a Parent component
below called EventCallBackParent.

```
        @page "/eventcallbackparent"

        <h3>EventCallBackParent</h3>

        <div>
            <EventCallBackChild onDoneButtonClicked=" "></EventCallBackChild>
        </div>
```

Here is the c# class/code for my Parent component

```
        public partial class EventCallBackParent
            {

                public async void Done()
                {
                    //Call a method here
                    ModalDisplay = "none";
                    ModalClass = "";
                    StateHasChanged();
                }
            }
```

Here is what my child component looks like

```
        <h3>EventCallBackChild</h3>

        <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="card" @onclick="DoneButtonClicked">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Standard</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @code {
         
            [Parameter]
            public EventCallback onDoneButtonClicked { get; set; }

            protected async Task DoneButtonClicked()
            {

            }
        }
```

Here is what I want to happen. When the standard card is clicked I want to
call the Done method in my parent component. Is this possible? If yes, how
can I go about it?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you have already declared an `EventCallback` parameter in your child component, you just need to invoke that callback within the `DoneButtonClicked` method:

```cs
[Parameter]
public EventCallback onDoneButtonClicked { get; set; }

protected async Task DoneButtonClicked()
{
    await onDoneButtonClicked.InvokeAsync();
}
```

Inside your parent component, you will then have to link this `onDoneButtonClicked` parameter of the child component with your parent component’s `Done` method:

```
<div>
    <EventCallBackChild onDoneButtonClicked="Done"></EventCallBackChild>
</div>
```

Comment: Literally every time I use an EventCallback in Blazor, I stop and think "What if I was still using Web Forms?"  Then I look at the sun shining, listen to the birds singing outside my window, and understand what it means when people say life is good. :D

Comment: Works like a charm. Great solution

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative could be to pass the parent component to the child

Parent:

```
<div>
    <EventCallBackChild Parent="this"></EventCallBackChild>
</div>

@code {
   public void Done() {
      // code...

      // Don't forget to call StateHasChanged
      StateHasChanged();
   }
}
```

Child:

```
[Parameter]
public ParentComponent Parent { get; set; }

protected void DoneButtonClicked()
{
    Parent.Done();
}
```

Note: This answer is an alternative, but may be not the best answer for this particular use case.